# How to get cookie or session via snoopy class?

Tags: session, snoopy

I want to login to other website and find some information about my account. So i used snoopy class to login.

```
$snoopy=new snoopy;
$url="http://website.com/login";
$index="http://website.com";

$info['txtUserId']="$username";
$info['txtPassword']="$password";
$snoopy->submit($url,$info);
$snoopy->setcookies();
$snoopy->fetch($index);
$result = $snoopy->results;
$header = $snoopy->headers;
echo print_r($snoopy->headers, TRUE);
echo $result;
```

And next is the problem. other page that represent information i want isn't work because session didn't be maintained.

There is no session information in headers array. To find some information, i have to maintain Session.

But i don't know how to find Session. Is there any method to find cookie or session in  snoopy class? i make an effort to find how to do, but i couldn't find it! Please let me know!